# Missing slug learning vue.js

Tags: vue.js

The whole point of this is trying to go from favorites tab straight into the lesson I liked.
Console is saying that the slug is undefined and I dont know what to do. Would be great if anybody could help me. Tried some things but didnt work as this is not only my code trying to just add a simple thing but it is really hard for me would be great if anybody could help me.

This is what it says in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
        at onClick (favourite.vue?0d11:9)
        at eval (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:315)
        at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
        at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163)
        at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:173)
        at HTMLElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:301)
```

Code:

```html
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <a-header />
    <ion-content>
      <!-- <h4 v-if="!lessons">Zatiaľ si si nič nepridal do obľubených lekcií</h4> -->
      <h4 v-if="!lessons || !lessons.length">Zatiaľ si si nič nepridal do obľubených lekcií</h4>
        <div v-else>
          <div v-for="lesson in lessons" :key="lesson.id" class="item-wrapper">
            <ion-item @click="$router.push({name:'lesson', params:{courseSlug:course.slug, lessonSlug:lesson.slug }})" lines="none"> <P>{{lesson.name}}</P> </ion-item>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import aHeader from '@/plugins/app/_components/a-header.vue'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import wAxios from '@/plugins/w/axios'

export default  {
  name: 'oblubene',
  components: { aHeader },
  data() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    return {
      lessons: [],
      lesson: null,
      
    }
  },
  computed: {
        ...mapGetters('wAuth', [
            'user'
        ]),
    },

  async created() {
    const lessonIds = this.user.lessons_stars.map(lesson => lesson.lesson_id)

    for(const id of lessonIds) {
      const lesson = await wAxios.get(`https://open-academy.sk/cms/api/lessons/${id}`)
      this.lessons.push(lesson.data)
    }
  
    
  }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: lesson is declared null you can declare it with empty object letsson: {} to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have shadowing variables: the `lesson in lessons` of `v-for` and the `lesson` in `data()`.

Here, it tries to reference the `data.lesson`, which is `null`.

```js
data() {
    return {
      lessons: [],
      lesson: null, // <-- to remove
    }
  },
```

Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two props in the template that have a `.slug` reference: `course.slug` and `lesson.slug`. `lesson` is the iterator declared in the `v-for`, but **`course`** is not defined anywhere in the code in question.

To resolve the issue, you need to declare `course` (e.g., as a data property):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lessons: [],
      course: {
        slug: 'my-slug'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jOBRMgo)